# PHP function.fopen failed to open stream: Permission denied

Tags: php, fopen

I'm running apache on ubuntu 12 and i can't open a specific file with the fopen function. I can open other files in the same php file.
Here is the error:

> Warning: fopen(file.txt) [function.fopen]: failed to open stream: Permission denied in /.../.../.../.../....php on line 10
>   Warning: fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /.../.../.../.../....php on line 11
>   Warning: fclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /.../.../.../.../....php on line 12
>   Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /.../.../.../.../....php:10) in /.../.../.../.../....php on line 20

My Code:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $username = $_SESSION['username'];
    $amount = $_SESSION['amount'];
    $message = $_SESSION['message'];
    $send = "$username donated $amount";
    $Vdata = file_get_contents('donation.txt');
    $cumoney = file_get_contents('money.txt');
    $newmoney = $amount + $cumoney;
    $handle4 = fopen("money.txt", "w");
    fwrite($handle4, $newmoney);
    fclose($handle4);
    if($Vdata == $send){
        $handle = fopen("donation.txt", "w");
        fwrite($handle, $username ." donated  ". $amount);
        fclose($handle);
        $handle2 = fopen("donationmsg.txt", "w");
        fwrite($handle2, $message);
        fclose($handle2);
        header ("Location: ...");
    }else{
        $handle = fopen("donation.txt", "w");
        fwrite($handle, $username ." donated ". $amount);
        fclose($handle);
        $handle2 = fopen("donationmsg.txt", "w");
        fwrite($handle2, $message);
        fclose($handle2);
        header ("Location: ...");
    }
?>
```

Comment: Could you post your code?

Comment: the problem is when i'm opening money.txt

Comment: wow ... you need some indenting there my friend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously PHP doesn't have write access to the file.
This being on Ubuntu PHP runs as the same user as Apache, so make sure the file is writable by the `www-data` group.

```
user@host:/path/to/your/file# chgrp www-data yourfile.txt
user@host:/path/to/your/file# chmod g+w yourfile.txt
```

Comment: I cannot add the +w, doesn't work. I tried chgrp www-data dir but didn't worked

Comment: Sorry, I got my commands mixed up. I updated the answer with commands testet to work on my Ubuntu installation.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a permissions issue.  You should make sure that you and your script will have the permissions to access that file and the directory that encloses it.